# WHile uploading my laravel 6 project to 000webhosting, I got error like this:

Tags: php, laravel

(1/1) LogicException
The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLFdl.jpg)

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30054 Might be of help

Comment: This is not anything to do with uploading the project, this is from running the project :)

Comment: https://github.com/BookStackApp/BookStack/issues/735